# Identity of modified Bessel functions

Tags: power-series, bessel-functions, theta-functions

Is there something similar to [Jacobi's anger expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi%E2%80%93Anger_expansion) for *powers* of modified Bessel functions?

What I mean is an evaluation of the series $$ \sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}n\theta}\left(I_n(x)\right)^m $$ where $x>0,\theta\in\mathbb{R}$ and $m\in\mathbb{N}$ and large?

I would like to prove the conjectured identity $$ \lim_{m\to\infty}\frac{\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}n\theta}\left(I_n(x)\right)^m}{\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\left(I_n(x)\right)^m} = 1 \qquad(\theta\in[0,2\pi))\,.$$

It seems to me like this problem is somewhat related to the following intution:

One could think of $\mathbb{Z}\ni n \mapsto \exp(-x)I_n(x)$ as a [discrete Gaussian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale_space_implementation#The_discrete_Gaussian_kernel), i.e., \begin{align} \sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}n\theta}\left(I_n(x)\right)^m &= \exp(+mx)\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}n\theta}\left(\exp(-x)I_n(x)\right)^m\\&\approx \exp(+mx)\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}n\theta}\exp(-xmn^2)\\&=\exp(mx)\Theta_3(\theta/2,\exp(-mx/2)) \end{align}where $\Theta_3$ is the [Jacobi elliptic theta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_elliptic_functions), and then Mathematica says $$ \lim_{m\to\infty} \frac{\Theta_3(\theta/2,\exp(-mx/2)) }{\Theta_3(0,\exp(-mx/2)) } = 1\,. $$

However it is not clear how to make this rigorous...